# javafx TableView with dynamic ContextMenu on rows

Tags: javafx, event-handling, tableview, contextmenu

I'm trying to make a java media player with DLNA Control Point.

There is a table with media files.
With JavaFX TableView, what I have learned, within the setRowFactory callback, we can add listeners on events, generated by table elements properties. All event types of TableView are fired only on internal table data changes.
I can't find a way to get to the table rows in case of some external event or logic, and to modify, for example, the ContextMenu for each row.

Each row in a table represents a media file. The ContextMenu initially has only "Play" (locally) and "Delete" menu items. 
For instance, a DLNA renderer device has appeared on the network. DLNA discovery thread has fired an event and I want to add a "Play to this device" menu item to the context menu of each table row. Respectively, I will need to remove this item, as soon as the corresponding device will go off.

How to hook to the ContextMenu of each row from outside of the rowFactory stuff?

Here's the code of the table and row factory

```
    public FileManager(GuiController guiController) {

        gCtrl = guiController;
        gCtrl.fileName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FileTableItem, String>("Name"));
        gCtrl.fileType.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FileTableItem, String>("Type"));
        gCtrl.fileSize.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FileTableItem, String>("Size"));
        gCtrl.fileTime.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FileTableItem, String>("modifiedTime"));


        gCtrl.filesTable.setRowFactory(tv -> {
            TableRow<FileTableItem> row = new TableRow<>();
            row.emptyProperty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isEmpty) -> {
                if (!isEmpty) {
                    FileTableItem file = row.getItem();
                    ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

                    if (file.isPlayable()) {
                        row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                            if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                                gCtrl.playMedia(file.getAbsolutePath());
                            }
                        });

                        MenuItem playMenuItem = new MenuItem("Play");
                        playMenuItem.setOnAction(event -> {
                            gCtrl.playMedia(file.getAbsolutePath());
                        });
                        contextMenu.getItems().add(playMenuItem);
                    }

                    if (file.canWrite()) {
                        MenuItem deleteMenuItem = new MenuItem("Delete");
                        deleteMenuItem.setOnAction(event -> {
                            row.getItem().delete();
                        });
                        contextMenu.getItems().add(deleteMenuItem);
                    }
                    row.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
                }
            });
            return row;
        });
        gCtrl.filesTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    }
    ...
    public class FileTableItem extends File {
    ...
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: One method is to attach to the `TableView`s `onContextMenuRequested`, and change the context menu according to the currently selected row.  A different approach would be to have all possible menu items, and bind each `disable` or `visible` property to an appropriate expression based on the selected item.

Comment: it's not the case to add all possible menu items, cause, for example, we can't know which DLNA devices will appear on the network.

"onContextMenuRequested" - is interesting approach - that's way we can update the ContextMenu each time it is called. 
I'm afraid It may be less efficient and more time consuming than background update upon external event. But I will try. 
Which event listener can be attached to it ?

Comment: OK, I got it working with row.setOnContextMenuRequested  - thanks a lot!

But I'm still curious -  is it the only possible way ?

It's very strange if we can not access TableView rows directly with something like getRows

Comment: @Liphtier Bear in mind that there aren't row instances for every item in the table view (rows are cells). Even if you did get a reference to a row instance, the item it represents may change at essentially arbitrary times. So a `getRows()` functionality would probably not be as useful as you think it would be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaFX generally follows MVC/MVP type patterns. In a table view, the `TableRow` is part of the view: therefore to change the appearance of the table row (including the content of the context menu associated with it in this case), you should let it observe some kind of model, and to change what is displayed in the context menu you change that model.

I'm not entirely sure if I've understood your use case correctly, but I think I understand that each item in the table may have a different set of devices associated with it. So you would have an entity class looking something like this:

```
public class FileTableItem extends File {

    private final ObservableList<Device> devices = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public ObservableList<Device> getDevices() {
        return devices ;
    }
}
```

When you create the table row, you need it to observe the list of devices associated with its current item; you can do this with a `ListChangeListener`. Of course, the item being displayed at any given time by a row can change at arbitrary times beyond your control (when the user scrolls the table, for example), so you need to observe the row's item property and make sure the `ListChangeListener` is observing the correct list of items. Here is some code that achieves this:

```
TableView<FileTableItem> filesTable = new TableView<>();
filesTable.setRowFactory(tv -> {
    TableRow<FileTableItem> row = new TableRow<>();
    ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
    ListChangeListener<FileTableItem> changeListener = (ListChangeListener.Change<? extends FileTableItem> c) -> 
        updateMenu(menu, row.getItem().getDevices());

    row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
        if (oldItem != null) {
            oldItem.getDevices().removeListener(changeListener);
        }
        if (newItem == null) {
            contextMenu.getItems().clear();
        } else {
            newItem.getDevices().addListener(changeListener);
            updateMenu(menu, newItem.getDevices());
        }
    });

    row.emptyProperty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isNowEmpty) -> 
         row.setContextMenu(isNowEmpty ? null : menu));

    return row ;
});

// ...

private void updateMenu(ContextMenu menu, List<Device> devices) {
    menu.getItems().clear();
    for (Device device : devices) {
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem(device.toString());
        item.setOnAction(e -> { /* ... */ });
        menu.getItems().add(item);
    }

}
```

This will now automatically update the context menu if the list of devices changes.

In the comments below your question you said you wanted there to be a `getRows()` method in the table. There isn't such a method, partly because the design is using a MVC approach as described. Even if there were, it wouldn't really help: suppose the list of devices for an item scrolled out of view changed - in that case there would not be a `TableRow` corresponding to that item, so you would not be able to get a reference to a row to change its context menu. Instead, with the setup described, you would simply update the model at the point in the code where you intend to update the table row.

You might need to modify this if you have menu items that are not dependent on the list, etc, but this should be enough to show the idea.

Here is a SSCCE. In this example, there are initially 20 items in the table, with no devices attached. The context menu for each shows just a "Delete" option which deletes the item. Instead of a background task which updates the items, I mimicked this with some controls. You can select an item in the table and add devices to it by pressing the "Add device" button: you will subsequently see "Play on device...." appearing in its context menu. Similarly "Remove device" will remove the last device in the list. The "Delay" check box will delay the addition or removal of a device by two seconds: this allows you to press the button and then (quickly) open the context menu; you will see the context menu update while it is being shown.

```
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class DynamicContextMenuInTable extends Application {

    private int deviceCount = 0 ;

    private void addDeviceToItem(Item item) {
        Device newDevice = new Device("Device "+(++deviceCount));
        item.getDevices().add(newDevice);
    }

    private void removeDeviceFromItem(Item item) {
        if (! item.getDevices().isEmpty()) {
            item.getDevices().remove(item.getDevices().size() - 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Item, String> itemCol = new TableColumn<>("Item");
        itemCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getName()));
        table.getColumns().add(itemCol);

        table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
            TableRow<Item> row = new TableRow<>();
            ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();

            MenuItem delete = new MenuItem("Delete");
            delete.setOnAction(e -> table.getItems().remove(row.getItem()));

            menu.getItems().add(delete);

            ListChangeListener<Device> deviceListListener = c -> 
                updateContextMenu(row.getItem(), menu);

            row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
                if (oldItem != null) {
                    oldItem.getDevices().removeListener(deviceListListener);
                }
                if (newItem != null) {
                    newItem.getDevices().addListener(deviceListListener);
                    updateContextMenu(row.getItem(), menu);
                }
            });

            row.emptyProperty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isNowEmpty) -> 
                row.setContextMenu(isNowEmpty ? null : menu));

            return row ;
        });

        CheckBox delay = new CheckBox("Delay");

        Button addDeviceButton = new Button("Add device");
        addDeviceButton.disableProperty().bind(table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());
        addDeviceButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            Item selectedItem = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if (delay.isSelected()) {
                PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
                pause.setOnFinished(evt -> {
                    addDeviceToItem(selectedItem);
                });
                pause.play();
            } else {
                addDeviceToItem(selectedItem);
            }
        });

        Button removeDeviceButton = new Button("Remove device");
        removeDeviceButton.disableProperty().bind(table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());
        removeDeviceButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            Item selectedItem = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() ;
            if (delay.isSelected()) {
                PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
                pause.setOnFinished(evt -> removeDeviceFromItem(selectedItem));
                pause.play();
            } else {
                removeDeviceFromItem(selectedItem);
            }
        });

        HBox buttons = new HBox(5, addDeviceButton, removeDeviceButton, delay);
        BorderPane.setMargin(buttons, new Insets(5));
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table, buttons, null, null, null);

        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 20; i++) {
            table.getItems().add(new Item("Item "+i));
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void updateContextMenu(Item item, ContextMenu menu) {
        if (menu.getItems().size() > 1) {
            menu.getItems().subList(1, menu.getItems().size()).clear();
        }
        for (Device device : item.getDevices()) {
            MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("Play on "+device.getName());
            menuItem.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Play "+item.getName()+" on "+device.getName()));
            menu.getItems().add(menuItem);
        }
    }

    public static class Device {
        private final String name ;

        public Device(String name) {
            this.name = name ;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name ;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getName();
        }
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final ObservableList<Device> devices = FXCollections.observableArrayList() ;

        private final String name ;

        public Item(String name) {
            this.name = name ;
        }

        public ObservableList<Device> getDevices() {
            return devices ;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name ;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There're two problems here:
1. My  DLNA devices list is a ConurrentHashMap and is not part of FileTableItem and GUI. It is maintained by other module that can not depend on FXCollections.observableArrayList.

2. It's not clear what you are doing here: 
Even if I will wrap the external devices list locally into observable list, row.itemProperty().addListener will catch events and update menu only on table data change, e.g. on change in files, not in devices! This is the problem. And ListChangeListener  seems to do nothing, at least in a way I tried to use it.

Comment: Updated with some clarification about the listeners and how to implement using this approach. Note that the `item` property doesn't only change when the data model changes, it changes when the row is reused to display a new item, for example when the user scrolls the table. The `ListChangeListener` observes the list of devices; the listener on the item property merely ensures it is observing the *correct* list of devices.

Comment: All right, I've got the idea and worked it out in this way.   I had to realize that wrapping my external Map into local observable won't work since: _"that mutation operations made directly to the underlying map are not reported to observers of any ObservableMap that wraps it."_.  So I  had to  create a local ObservableMap and it will be modified by DLNA discovery event listener.  Finally I put the observed map in the  file manager class and not  in file item, because I don't need separate devices list per item.    
Thank you!

Comment: Yes, indeed - you need to make sure the observable collection is aware of the change so that it can notify listeners. The other way to go is to let your service register callbacks, which allows your service to be free of JavaFX API (though just using collections is not a big deal imho). There's a really nice [article by Adam Bien](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javafxinteg-2062777.html) on strategies for integrating JavaFX with background services.

Answer (score 0):

With an advice from [sillyfly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4185959/sillyfly) I got the working solution, however it may potentially have performance drawbacks. So it would be interesting to find a better one.

```
class FileManager {


    private GuiController gCtrl;

    protected Menu playToSub = new Menu("Play to...");
    Map<String, MenuItem> playToItems = new HashMap<String, MenuItem>();

    public FileManager(GuiController guiController) {

        gCtrl = guiController;

        gCtrl.fileName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FileTableItem, String>("Name"));
        gCtrl.fileType.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FileTableItem, String>("Type"));
        gCtrl.fileSize.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FileTableItem, String>("Size"));
        gCtrl.fileTime.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FileTableItem, String>("modifiedTime"));

        gCtrl.filesTable.setRowFactory(tv -> {
            TableRow<FileTableItem> row = new TableRow<>();
            row.emptyProperty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isEmpty) -> {
                if (!isEmpty) {
                    FileTableItem file = row.getItem();
                    ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

                    if (file.isPlayable()) {
                        row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                            if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                                gCtrl.mainApp.playFile = file.getName();
                                gCtrl.playMedia(file.getAbsolutePath());
                            }
                        });

                        MenuItem playMenuItem = new MenuItem("Play");
                        playMenuItem.setOnAction(event -> {
                            gCtrl.mainApp.playFile = file.getName();
                            gCtrl.playMedia(file.getAbsolutePath());
                        });
                        contextMenu.getItems().add(playMenuItem);
                    }

                    if (file.canWrite()) {
                        MenuItem deleteMenuItem = new MenuItem("Delete");
                        deleteMenuItem.setOnAction(event -> {
                            row.getItem().delete();
                        });
                        contextMenu.getItems().add(deleteMenuItem);
                    }
                    row.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
                }
            });
            row.setOnContextMenuRequested((event) -> {

                /// Here, just before showing the context menu we can decide what to show in it
                /// In this particular case it's OK, but it may be time expensive in general
                if(! row.isEmpty()) {
                    if(gCtrl.mainApp.playDevices.size() > 0) {
                        if(! row.getContextMenu().getItems().contains(playToSub)) {
                            row.getContextMenu().getItems().add(1, playToSub);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if(row.getContextMenu().getItems().contains(playToSub)) {
                            row.getContextMenu().getItems().remove(playToSub);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            return row;
        });
        gCtrl.filesTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    }

    /// addPlayToMenuItem and removePlayToMenuItem are run from Gui Controller
    /// which in turn is notified by events in UPNP module
    /// The playTo sub menu items are managed here
    public void addPlayToMenuItem(String uuid, String name, URL iconUrl) {
        MenuItem playToItem = new PlayToMenuItem(uuid, name, iconUrl);
        playToItems.put(uuid, playToItem);
        playToSub.getItems().add(playToItem);
    }

    public void removePlayToMenuItem(String uuid) {
        if(playToItems.containsKey(uuid)) {
            playToSub.getItems().remove(playToItems.get(uuid));
            playToItems.remove(uuid);
        }
    }

    public class PlayToMenuItem extends MenuItem {
        PlayToMenuItem(String uuid, String name, URL iconUrl) {
            super();
            if (iconUrl != null) {
                Image icon = new Image(iconUrl.toString());
                ImageView imgView = new ImageView(icon);
                imgView.setFitWidth(12);
                imgView.setPreserveRatio(true);
                imgView.setSmooth(true);
                imgView.setCache(true);
                setGraphic(imgView);
            }
            setText(name);
            setOnAction(event -> {
                gCtrl.mainApp.playFile =    gCtrl.filesTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getName();
                gCtrl.mainApp.startRemotePlay(uuid);
            });
        }
    }

    /// Other class methods and members

}
```